# Error updating a select box by ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to update a selectbox that depends on another selectbox. Depending on the first one, it will search all those records that are related. Should work, this I am doing at the device login but I am getting the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Usuarios::SessionsControllerController):
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `const_get'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:70:in `controller_reference'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:60:in `controller'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:39:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  rack-pjax (1.0.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.2.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.2.0.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.7.0) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:9:in `require'
  bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (2.0.0) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  spring (2.0.0) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  spring (2.0.0) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  spring (2.0.0) lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
  spring (2.0.0) bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  spring (2.0.0) lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
  spring (2.0.0) lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
  bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:3:in `load'
  bin/rails:3:in `<main>'


  Rendered /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /home/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (9.7ms)
```

this is my new.html.erb (view->devise->sessions)

```
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
      <h1>Login Form</h1>

      <div class="forml">
      <div class="form-group">

          <div >
            <%= f.text_field :login, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder =>"Username or Email",  :required => ""  %>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div >

            <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder =>"Password",  :required => ""  %>

          </div>
          <%= select_tag :empresa, options_for_select(@empresas.map{|e|[e.Empresa, e.id]}), :'data-remote' => 'true', :'data-url' => url_for(:controller => 'sessions_controller', :action => 'busqueda_sucursales', format: 'js') %>

          <div id="sucursales"><%= render 'sucursales' %></div>



        </div>
</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                <div class="checkbox-inline col-md-5">
                  <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
                  <%= f.label :remember_me %>
                </div>
            <% end -%>
          </div>
        <div>

            <%= f.submit "Log in", :class => "btn btn-default submit col-md-10"%>
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="separator">
          </div>
        <% end %>
```

this is my partial _sucursales.html.erb(view->devise->sessions)

```
<div class="form-group">
   <%= label_tag :sucursal, "Selecciona sucursal:" %>
   <div class="">
    <%= select_tag :sucursal, options_for_select(@sucursales.map{|e|[e.Sucursal, e.IdEmpresa]}), class: "form-control js-example-basic-single" %>
   </div>
</div>
```

this is my busqueda_sucursales.js.erb (view->devise->sessions)

```
$("#sucursales").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("sucursales"))%>")
```

this is my sessions_controller.rb (controllers->usuarios)

```
class Usuarios::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
# before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_in_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  def busqueda_sucursales #Actualiza las sucursales concorde a las empresas en el acceso
    @sucursales = Empresa.where("empresamadre_id = ?", params[:empresa])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def new
    @empresas = Empresamadre.all
    @sucursales = Empresa.where("empresamadre_id = ?", @empresas.first.id)
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  private
  def sign_up_params
    allow = [:email, :usuario, :password, :password_confirmation, :nombre, :idempresa]
    params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
  end
end
```

this is my routes.rb

```
devise_for :usuarios, controllers: {
    registrations: "usuarios/registrations",
    sessions: "usuarios/sessions",
    passwords: "usuarios/passwords"}
    resources :usuarios do
      get 'usuarios_check', :on => :collection
      get 'usuarios_check2', :on => :collection
    end

  get 'usuarios/sessions_controller/busqueda_sucursales', as: 'busqueda_sucursales'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the first line of your error, it seemed off to see the word Controller repeated:

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Usuarios::SessionsControllerController):`

This line:

`<%= select_tag :empresa, options_for_select(@empresas.map{|e|[e.Empresa, e.id]}), :'data-remote' => 'true', :'data-url' => url_for(:controller => 'sessions_controller', :action => 'busqueda_sucursales', format: 'js') %>`

replace `:controller => 'sessions_controller'` with `:controller => 'sessions'`

See the examples here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Correct, also I must put the following code to make it work:    devise_scope :usuario do
      get 'usuarios/sessions/busqueda_sucursales', to: 'usuarios/sessions#busqueda_sucursales', as: 'busqueda_sucursales'
      
    end